# removing some Grey Object on View Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I was trying to use navigation controller. But end up in adding some grey area on my view controller. 
I have tried to remove it but failed.

1. I have checked if there is some navigation controller item has been added under my view but cannot find.
2. I cannot even click that item.

Can some one help me in removing this grey area. It was added when I was trying to add navigation bar controller from the library
I have added the image. Please check. I cannot remove it.
Actually I added the navigation controller but I think I cannot add it correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
How
1) opened the Main.storyboard file in external editor i.e. Text Edit
tried to search which xml element with title equals to some button which is close to this like button 2 or 0
i found tool bar item which was added with mistake. 
here is the code i removed it and it worked.
i have given two options to remove. Even if the code which is mentioned below in the heading Removed (2) is there , still they grey item will be shown there. 
The annoying thing is ,we cannot select this item and it is no visible in the item hierarchy under the view.

Removed (1)

```
<toolbarItems>
                        <barButtonItem title="Back" width="103" id="732-cW-LpG">
                            <connections>
                                <segue destination="BEC-Jo-iar" kind="unwind" unwindAction="cancelToPlayersViewController:" id="ddb-5K-wuv"/>
                            </connections>
                        </barButtonItem>
                    </toolbarItems>

<simulatedToolbarMetrics key="simulatedBottomBarMetrics"/>
```

Removed (2)